# Cordova facebook connect plugin java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: cordova, adt

After running cordova build, I use eclipse to run my app, and got "cordova facebook connect plugin failed on init." and my log:

```
W/System.err( 1234): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 1234):    at 
 org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.execute(ConnectPlugin.java:203)
W/System.err( 1234):    at 
 org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
W/System.err( 1234):    at  
 org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
W/System.err( 1234):    at 
 org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
W/System.err( 1234):    at 
 org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
W/System.err( 1234):    at  
 com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1234):    at   
   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
W/System.err( 1234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 1234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
W/System.err( 1234):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

index.js:

```
  var app = {
      // Application Constructor
      initialize: function() {
          this.bindEvents();
      },
      // Bind Event Listeners
      //
      // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
      // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
      bindEvents: function() {
          document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
      },
      // deviceready Event Handler
      //
      // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
      // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
      onDeviceReady: function() {
          app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
           FB.init({
               appId: "439058150542",
               nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
               useCachedDialogs: false
           });
          angular.element(document).ready(function() {
              angular.bootstrap(document, ['Myapp']);
          });
      },
      // Update DOM on a Received Event
      receivedEvent: function(id) {
      }
  };
```